# Get content from file and do a dig command

Tags: powershell

Im trying to get a script to work PS script. To get content from a *.txt  file and do a dig command

I got this so far..

```
path = ".\domain.txt"
$mxdomain = Get-Content $path

foreach ($domain in $mxdomain)   dig $domain MX +short
```

Comment: Ok, So what's your question?. Are you getting any errors/exceptions?

Comment: You'll need to wrap the command for `foreach()` inside curly brackets `{...}`

Comment: Used google a bit more and thats tru I need to use the brackets.. so the solution for me was/is

foreach ($domain in $mxdomain) {
Resolve-DnsName -Name $domain -Type MX -Server $dnsserver | select Name,Type,NameExchange }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you [Theo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9898643/theo) and [Marko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16926886/marko). Posting your suggestion as an answer to help other community members.

You can  wrap the command for `foreach()` inside curly brackets `{...}`

`foreach ($domain in $mxdomain) { Resolve-DnsName -Name $domain -Type MX -Server $dnsserver | select Name,Type,NameExchange }`